# Sum the powers to n

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

## Directions

Write a program that, given an input integer *n* (`n >= 0`), outputs the **smallest positive integer** *m* where:

- `n = a[1]^b[1] + a[2]^b[2] + a[3]^b[3] + ... + a[k]^b[k]`
- `a` and `b` are finite sequences of the same length
- all elements of `a` are less than `m`
- all elements of `b` are less than `m`
- all elements of `a` are **different** and integers `a[x] >= 0`
- all elements of `b` are **different** and integers `b[x] >= 0`
- `a[x]` and `b[x]` are not both 0 (since 0^0 is indeterminate)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.

## Examples

```
In 0 -> Out 1
Possible Sum: 

In 1 -> Out 2
Possible Sum: 1^0

In 2 -> Out 3
Possible Sum: 2^1

In 3 -> Out 3
Possible Sum: 2^1 + 1^0

In 6 -> Out 4
Possible Sum: 2^2 + 3^0 + 1^1

In 16 -> Out 5
Possible Sum: 2^4

In 17 -> Out 4
Possible Sum: 3^2 + 2^3

In 23 -> Out 6
Possible Sum: 5^1 + 3^0 + 2^4 + 1^3

In 24 -> Out 5
Possible Sum: 4^2 + 2^3

In 27 -> Out 4
Possible Sum: 3^3

In 330 -> Out 7
Possible Sum: 6^1 + 4^3 + 3^5 + 2^4 + 1^0
```

Comment: How are we supposed to make a sequence of unique, nonnegative integers that has a non-infinite sum?

Comment: Also, the first case doesn't make sense because a sum with 0 terms would suffice.

Comment: @feersum I don't quite understand your question. My solution to this is a brute force search of all combinations where `m<2` then `m<3` then `m<4` etc. until I find a sum that equals `n`. Also, I thought about having the sum for `0` be no terms, but then what is the output? m > ?

Comment: My first comment was because the way it is written suggests an infinite sequence. For the second issue, I suggest that the minimum input is 1.

Comment: @feersum Alright, I will change the example case. And I will also try to notate a finite sequence somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: For finite sequences, you would usually do something like `n = a[1]^b[1] + a[2]^b[2] + ... + a[k]^b[k]`.

Comment: Nice question. Just one quibble on the first test case: `a` and `b` are finite sequences of length `0`, so there is no integer `m` which doesn't satisfy the constraints, and since there is no smallest integer the answer is not defined. Possible fixes would be to ask for the smallest natural number `m` (in which case you should change the expected answer there to `0`) or for the smallest positive integer `m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### GolfScript (59 chars)

```
~:T),{),.0{2$0-{2${{4$2$^}2*@3$\?4$+f~}%\;~}%+\;\;}:f~T&}?)
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc2JwoKfjpUKSx7KSwuMHsyJDAtezIke3s0JDIkXn0yKkAzJFw%2FNCQrZn59JVw7fn0lK1w7XDt9OmZ%2BVCZ9Pyk%3D)

This uses recursion to enumerate the values achieveable for a given `m` and searches for the first `m` which works. It's lightly inspired by [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44666/194) but quite different in implementation.

#### Dissection

```
~:T                  # Evaluate input and store in T (for Target)
),{                  # Search [0 1 ... T] for the first m which matches a predicate
  ),.0               #   Push [0 ... m] to the stack twice and then 0
                     #   Stack holds: possibleAs possibleBs sum
  {                  #   Define the recursive function f
    2$0-{            #     Map over A in possibleAs (except 0)
      2${            #       Map over B in possibleBs (except 0)
        {4$2$^}2*    #         Duplicate respective possibles and remove selected values
        @3$\?4$+     #         Compute sum' = sum + A^B
        f            #         Recursive call gives an array [sums]
        ~            #         Push the sums to the stack individually
        }%           #       End map: this collects the sums into a combined array
      \;             #       Pop A, leaving just the combined [sums] inside the map
      ~              #       Repeat the trick: push to the stack individually
    }%               #     End map, collecting into a combined array
                     #     Stack now holds: possibleAs possibleBs sum [sums]
    +                #     Include the original sum in the array of reachable sums
    \;\;             #     Pop possibleAs and possibleBs
  }:f                #   End function definition
  ~                  #   Evaluate the function
  T&                 #   Test whether the sums contain T
}?                   # End search
)                    # Increment to get m
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 120

```python
f=lambda n,A,B:n*all(f(n-a**b,A-{a},B-{b})for a in A for b in B)
g=lambda n,m=1,M={0}:f(n,M-{0},M)and g(n,m+1,M|{m})or m
```

The function `f` is an auxiliary function that checks whether `n` can *not* be expressed as a sum of powers with distinct bases from `A` and exponents from `B`. It uses a natural recursive strategy: `n` must be nonzero, and we try every possible choice of base and and exponent and they all need to fail. We removing them from the allowed lists and decrease `n` by the corresponding amount.

The function `g` is the main function. It searches for an `m` that works. `M` is the set of allowed values up to `m-1`. We remove `0` from the allowed exponents to stop `0**0` (which Python evaluates to 1) from being used. This doesn't hurt anything Because `0**x` is a useless `0` for all other `x`.

Comment: You could probably change `n and all()` to `n*all()`.

Comment: @grc Ah, you don't actually need the short circuiting because it bottoms out. Thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 138 bytes

```py
from itertools import*
S=lambda n,m=0,R=[]:m*any(n==sum(map(pow,*C))for k in R for C in product(*tee(permutations(R,k))))or S(n,m+1,R+[m])
```

*(Thanks to @Jakube for all the tips)*

I've never learnt so much about the `itertools` module as I have from this one question. The last case takes about a minute.

We start by searching from `m = 1` and incrementing until we get a solution. To check for a solution we iterate over:

- `k = 0 to m-1`, where `k` is the number of terms in the solution
- All possible combination of terms (by zipping together two permutations of subsets of `[0, 1, ... m-1]` with size `k`), then summing and checking if we have `n`

Note that we iterate `k` up to `m-1` — even though technically `m` terms are possible in total, there's always a solution with `m-1` terms as `0^0` is not allowed and `0^b` contributes nothing. This is actually important because `0^0` is treated as 1 by Python, which seems like a problem, but it turns out not to matter!

Here's why.

Suppose a solution found erroneously uses `0^0` as 1, e.g. `3^2 + 1^1 + 0^0 = 11`. Since we only generate up to `m-1` terms, there must be some `j` we are not using as a base (here `j = 2`). We can swap out the base 0 for `j` to get a valid solution, here `3^2 + 1^1 + 2^0 = 11`.

Had we iterated up to all `m` terms, then we might have gotten incorrect solutions like `m = 2` for `n = 2`, via `0^0 + 1^1 = 2`.

Comment: Nice one. You can save 4 bytes by using imap though. 
`imap(pow,C,D) ... for C,D in`

Comment: @Jakube I'm actually looking through the doc for `itertools` as we speak :P I already have another saving — `tee`.

Comment: Me too. 
Also, my mistake. Why would someone suggest `imap`, when there is `map`?? -1 byte

Comment: The default parameter for `tee` is already `n=2`. Saves 2 bytes.

Comment: @Jakube Ahaha thanks. This is probably the first time I've ever used `map` with more than one iterable, and in fact this question's bring out a lot of firsts for me.

Comment: One last thing. If you go back to your `any`-construct, you can save 2 additional bytes: `m*any(n==sum ...)or S(n,m+1)`

Comment: @Jakube I can save another byte by passing in a list instead of having `range(m)`, but I feel like that's now intruding on your solution...

Comment: I don't mind. You can use it if you want.

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript (<strike>90</strike> 84 bytes)

```
[0.,.]](~:T),(+{:x;{:|2,{:c)|=x),^{c[1$x]=:A^x^:-;[|~-+@A-?+@A+@]}%}/+~}%.[]*T&}?)\;
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc2JwoKWzAuLC5dXSh%2BOlQpLCgrezp4O3s6fDIsezpjKXw9eCksXntjWzEkeF09OkFeeF46LTtbfH4tK0BBLT8rQEErQF19JX0vK359JS5bXSpUJn0%2FKVw7)

#### Dissection

```
[0.,.]             # Base case: [sum As Bs] is [0 [] []]
](~:T              # Collect it in an array of cases; fetch parameter, eval, store in T.
),(+               # Create array [1 2 ... T 0]. Putting 0 at the end means that it won't
                   # be reached except when T is 0, and nicely handles that special case.
{                  # Loop over the values from that array...
  :x;              #   ...assigning each in turn to x (and popping it from the stack)
  {                #   Stack holds array of [sum As Bs] cases; map them...

    :|             #     Store [sum As Bs] in |
    2,{:c          #     For c in [0 1]...
      )|=x),^      #       Get [0 1 ... x]^ either As or Bs, depending on c
      {            #       Map these legal new As or Bs respectively...
        c[1$x]=:A  #         Work out which of that value or x is the new A
        ^x^:-;     #         And the other one is the new B
        [          #         Begin gathering in an array
          |~       #           Push sum As Bs to the stack
          -+       #           Add - to Bs to get Bs'
          @A-?+    #           Rotate sum to top and add A^- to get sum'
          @A+      #           Rotate As to top and add A to get As'
          @        #           Final rotation to put elements in the right order
        ]          #         Gather in array [sum' As' Bs']
      }%           #       End map
    }/             #     End for
    +~             #     Push all the elements corresponding to x^B and A^x on to the stack
  }%               #   End map, collecting the untouched [sum As Bs] and all the new
                   #   [sum' As' Bs'] arrays into a new array of reached cases.
  .[]*T&           #   Flatten a copy of that array and filter to values equal to T.
                   #   This gives a truthy value iff we've found a way to make T.
}?                 # Loop until we get a truthy value, and push the corresponding x
)\;                # Increment to get the value of m and discard the array of cases
```

The most elegant trick is the handling of the special case for `0`.

Comment: I am really happy that CJam is this time not soo much shorter than standard python=P

Comment: @flawr, this is GolfScript, not CJam. CJam can probably be quite a bit shorter because it has a built-in for Cartesian products. And it might be that xnor's idea of a recursive function gives shorter GolfScript, too.

Comment: Oh sorry, just confused them=)

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <strike>143</strike> 130

```
import Data.List
p n=head$[1..]>>=(\m->[m|let x=permutations[0..m-1]>>=inits,a<-x,b<-x,sum(zipWith(\x y->x^y*signum(x+y))a b)==n])
```

Usage example: `p 23` -> `6`.

This is a simple brute force search. For every list `[0..0], [0..1], [0..2] ... [0..∞]` take all initial segments of the permutations (e.g. [0..2]: permutations: `[012], [102], [210], [120], [201], [021]`, initial segments for 1st permutation: `[0], [01], [012]`, 2nd: `[1], [10], [102]`, etc.). For every combination of 2 of those lists calculate the sum of powers. Stop when first one equals n.

Comment: you should use `>>=` rather than `concatMap`. they are just the same but with the arguments flipped.

Comment: @proudhaskeller: Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Python: 166 characters

```
from itertools import*;p=permutations
f=lambda n,r=[0]:any(n==sum(map(lambda x,y:(x+y>0)*x**y,a,b))for j in r for a,b in product(p(r,j),p(r,j)))*1or 1+f(n,r+[len(r)])
```

### Explanation

The function `f` creates all possible integers, that can be expressed as sum of powers of of numbers in `r`. If starts with `r = [0]`. If any of those integers is equal to `n`, it returns the length of `r`, otherwise it call itself recursively with an extended `r`.

The computation of the all integers, that can be expressed as sum is done with two loops. 
The first loop is the `for j in r`, which tells us the length of the expression (2^3 + 1^2 has length 2). The inner loop iterates over all combinations of permutations of `r` of length `j`. For each I calculate the sum of powers.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 219 <s>224</s>

Recursive function. Starting with m=1, I try all combinations of integer 1..m for bases and 0..m for exponents (0 base is useless given 0^0 == undefined).
If no solution found, increase m and try again.
Special case for input 0 (in my opinion that is an error in the specs anyway)

The C function recursively generates all combinations from an array of given length, so that

```
C(3, [1,2,3]) --> [[3,2,1], [3,1,2], [2,3,1], [2,1,3], [1,3,2], [1,2,3]]
```

The third level `every` is used to zip together the array a of bases and b of exponents (there is no `zip` function in JavaScript). Using `every` to stop early when there is a solution not using all elements in the two arrays.

```js
F=(n,j=1,k=[],
  C=(l,a,o=[],P=(l,a,i=l)=>{
    for(l||o.push(a);i--;)
      e=[...a],P(l-1,e.concat(e.splice(i,1)))
  })=>P(l,a)||o
)=>n&&C(k.push(j++),k)[E='every'](a=>C(j,[0,...k])[E](b=>a[E](x=>t-=Math.pow(x,b.pop()),t=n)))
?F(n,j,k):j
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```
;[0,1,2,3,6,16,17,23,24,27,330].map(x=>[x,F(x)])
```

*Output*

> [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3], [6, 4], [16, 5], [17, 4], [23, 6], [24, 5], [27, 4], [330, 7]]